# Can the framing structure support load for a second story on a house?

Tags: walls

I have an older home with 2 x 4 studs on first floor. I am remodeling the second story and want to add a 10 ft. with 2 x 6 walls. Can the first story support this load?

Comment: You are blindly asking on the internet if the first story of your home can handle a second floor?? You'll almost certainly need to have a structural engineer come to your home to verify what loads it can handle. Also, TURN OFF YOUR CAPSLOCK.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your project's engineer or general contractor.